# will the try block guard the destruction of local variables?

Tags: c++, exception

```
class A
  {
  public:
    ~A();
  };
A::~A()
  {
  std::cout<<"Destructor!!!\n"<<std::endl;
  std::exception e;
  throw e;
  }
void main()
  {
  try
    {
    A a;
    //A a1,a2;//This gives out two lines of "Destructor!!!" then the program terminates            
    }
  catch(std::exception)
    {
    std::cout<<"Caught!!!\n"<<std::endl;
    }
  }
```

I know it's a bad practice to emit exception in destructor. But its not illegal.
The above program goes into the catch block. It seems the `try` block is guarding the destruction of local variables.
However, if i uncomment the code, it gives something different. In this case, it seems the first exception is not handled and the terminates is caused by more than one exception. 
Now I'm not sure if the destruction of local variables when exciting function is guarded or not. I'm using VS2005 btw.

Comment: The program doesn't "crash"; it calls `std::terminate`, as specified.

Comment: Perhaps your compiler is broken? `Caught!!!` should never be printed. http://ideone.com/P9OfOl

Comment: On the other hand, perhaps I'm misunderstanding your question. Could you please include the output you expect and the output you are actually getting to your question.

Comment: @BillLynch I just tried with c++11 ,it does NOT printed "Caught". However, in C++ 98 ,it does. http://cpp.sh/4ior

Comment: In C++11, destructors are implicitly `noexcept`.

Comment: "I know it's a bad practice to emit exception in destructor." - and now you know why.

Comment: I don't think it is useful to discuss the behavior of a ten-year-old compiler.

Comment: @T.C. well. the real question here  is whether the destruction of local variables when exciting functions are guarded  by the try.

Comment: guys, the question is not really answered, is it?

Comment: the destruction of local variables is caused by the `}` of the block in which the local variables were declared.  This applies to all blocks, not just `try...catch` blocks.

Comment: @MikeNakis but the question is will the exception that was emitted during that destruction process be examined by the following catch block of that try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `try`/`catch` block will deal with just one exception. If you have two or more objects of type `A` constructed in a block, the destructor of each one of these objects will throw an exception. The first one exception thrown (from the object created last/destroyed first) can get handled. However, before the handler is reached, all other local objects are destroyed. When there is another `A` object in the block, it will be destroyed, too, throw an exception and, voila, there are two exceptions. When there are two unhandled exception outside of the destructor the system calls `std::terminate()` which needs to terminate the program.

With C++11 all destructors are implicitly defined to be `noexcept` or `noexcept(true)` (both are equivalent). The reason for this change is that move constructing and destroying a temporary should be `noexcept` by default. If you want to have throwing destructors with C++11 you'll need to declare the destructor as `noexcept(false)`, e.g.:

```
class A {
public:
    ~A() noexcept(false) { throw std::exception(); } // still a Bad Idea!!!
    // ...
};
```

When throwing an exception from a destructor you effectively need to be sure that the object is not destroyed as a result for stack-unwinding while dealing with an existing exception. Within the destructor it is OK to have exceptions as long as no exception escapes the destructor.

In practice, there is no safe way to know whether an object is destroyed as the result of stack-unwinding. Although legal from a language point of view, you are best off to never throw from a destructor.